# Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to know why does this code not execute? I'm trying to send my data from my device via POST method but there is no error. The app just finishes by itself on my device by communicating "My app was stopped.:

Here is execution:

```
KlientNameValue kn = new KlientNameValue(getApplicationContext());
kn.new  MyAsyncTask().execute(zam.klient.getNazwa(),zam.klient.getNip(),zam.klient.getAdres());
```

And here is code:

```
public class KlientNameValue {

List<NameValuePair> KlientNameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
Context context;
public KlientNameValue(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context=context;
}



 public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

      @Override protected Void doInBackground(String... params) { 
          // TODO     Auto-generated method stub 
          postData(params[0], params[1], params[2]);
      return null;

      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

      Toast.makeText(context , "Zlecenie zostało wysłane",
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }

      void postData(String nazwa, String nip, String adres) {
          HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("here is my default link :)");

      try { // Add your data

      KlientNameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      KlientNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Kli_imie", nazwa));
      KlientNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Kli_adres", adres));
      KlientNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair( "Kli_nr_telefonu",
      nip)); 



      httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity( KlientNameValuePairs));
      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
      //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity( 
      //      ZamowienieNameValuePairs)); // HttpResponse response1 =



      } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace(); }

      }

      }
```

}

Error:

```
02-15 17:45:24.695: E/AndroidRuntime(21890): at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:94) 
02-15 17:47:19.343: W/SingleClientConnManager(22288): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
 02-15 17:47:19.343: W/SingleClientConnManager(22288): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
```

Comment: _"Just app finish itself on device by comunicate "My app was stopped.38"_ It means that your app crashed. Show us the log please. Also in your constructor, it should be `this.context = context`.

Comment: @TGMCians 02-15 17:45:24.695: E/AndroidRuntime(21890):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:94)
02-15 17:47:19.343: W/SingleClientConnManager(22288): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
02-15 17:47:19.343: W/SingleClientConnManager(22288): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.

Comment: It's much easier to read the logcat if you edit your post with the **full** logcat and format in a code block.

Comment: @codeMagic here it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.

You are executing the http request two times that is completely wrong before you consume it. So remove the second `httpclient.execute(httppost);` because you have already execute this http request.

and call this

```
httpResponse.getEntity().consumeContent();
```

> Above method is called to indicate that the content of this entity is no longer required. All entity implementations are expected to release all allocated resources as a result of this method invocation

Comment: i've change that and still nothing.

Comment: Are you getting same error again? If you have updated then update the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
public static DefaultHttpClient getThreadSafeClient() {

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ClientConnectionManager mgr = client.getConnectionManager();
    HttpParams params = client.getParams();

    client = new DefaultHttpClient(
        new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,
            mgr.getSchemeRegistry()), params);

    return client;
}
```

use this  code so that your exception of free resource and allocate or being used will not come 
This exception can happen when two or more threads interact with a single `org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient`
or simply give new object to each request when and where ever you are calling you get or post http client request to interact with server to fetch the data or download the large file
like

```
String post_url="http://www.google.com";
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(Post_url);     
    httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpost);
    String response= EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
```

as you like in code to retrieve the response